# Problem generating GeoPoint in Android

Tags: android, location

I'm trying to create GeoPoints, but I couldn't so far.

```
double latitudeUpperLeft = -34.567645; 
double longitudeUpperLeft = -58.497734;
double latitudeBottomRight = -34.62558;
double longitudeBottomRight = -58.42495;

GeoPoint geoPointUpperLeft = calculateGeoPoint(latitudeUpperLeft, longitudeUpperLeft);
GeoPoint geoPointBottomRight = calculateGeoPoint(latitudeBottomRight, longitudeBottomRight);
```

This is the helper method:

```
public static GeoPoint calculateGeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
    Double latE6 = latitude * 1E6;
    Double lngE6 = longitude * 1E6;
    return  new GeoPoint(latE6.intValue(), lngE6.intValue());
}
```

I'm getting an InvocationTargetException on the return of the helper method, What could be wrong?
Thanks. Guillermo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer [in the anddev.org forum](http://www.anddev.org/map-problems-f26/fix-could-not-find-class-com-google-android-maps-geopoint-t11325.html).
The problem was  in the manifest, somehow it was missing this entry:

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

After adding it, it started to work.

Comment: haha this happens. you still can select your's as and answer. and have mine as a minor tweak. you need not waste two variables with boxing and unboxing them. or at least make them **final**.

Answer (score 5):

can you tell me if this works.

```
public static GeoPoint calculateGeoPoint(double latitude, double longitude) {
    return  new GeoPoint((int)(latitude * 1E6), (int)(longitude * 1E6));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Directly GeoPoint .You will follow the steps:

1)First you have data(Location) in degree formate. 
2)By the Equation you have to multiply it by 1000000 
3)now ,you have particular GEO POINT Location .

Like here ;if I have location like : Latitude:23.0395677 and Longitude:72.5660045° So, your GeoPoint(23039568,72566045);

You get the Perfect Location for it.